# What is "translate" keyword do in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, cloud9-ide, translate

Short question:
What is 'translate' word doing and why it's colored as special in my IDE?

Long question:
I am doing the Odin Project, and code in 04_pig_latin Ruby and RSpec exercise should look like this:

```
def translate(string) 
  # some code
end
```

Per the spec which I need to pass:

```
describe "#translate" do

  it "translates a word beginning with a vowel" do
    s = translate("apple")
    expect(s).to eq("appleay")
  end

end
```

In my Cloud9 IDE the word translate is colored blue (like `require` or `render`), so I assume that I can't use it as a method name and will need to change the given RSpec test to pass it. However, I saw that others doing this task are naming this method `translate` without any issues.
I haven't found anything about this "keyword" what could make it unique, I don't know what it's really doing, and don't know whether it's uniqueness comes from Ruby or Cloud9.

[Link to exercises repo](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/learn_ruby)

Comment: Your IDE is wrong. `translate` does not mean anything special in Ruby.

Comment: It's a function name, and that's how the IDE syntax-highlights function names.

Comment: cloud9IDE editor doesn't normally highlight method names in ruby files. So this is just an error. You can ignore it an carry on.

Comment: Thanks for responses.
However I'm still curious about behaviour in irb. Why 'start_with?' becomes undefined after that code was loaded?

Comment: I see, this only happens in irb and not in scripts. It's a shame this isn't your main question and that you have posted a screenshot instead of code, which is what you should really do.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the code causing this. Thanks for pointing this out. I will remember in future. It's not the first time when I think c9 IDE is acting weird, so that's why I am curious.

Comment: tadman has posted an answer to your first question and it's a great high-level overview of what's going on. However as it stands your post is actually two questions. I suggest you edit and remove the question regarding irb in this post (but *don't* delete this post) and re-post your irb related question as a new post/SO question. And remember, no screenshots. Post code and your error message.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590976/why-word-translate-is-messing-irb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Ruby syntax highlighting library often includes common phrases that are used in things like Rails. For example, `belongs_to`, while not a special keyword in a Ruby sense, is very common in Rails applications so it's often highlighted.

`translate` might be a special phrase as well as it's used by a lot of I18N libraries.

The only way to find out for sure is to look at the rules for syntax highlighting your editor uses. Usually there's a list of special method names in there.