# Why word 'translate' is messing irb?

Tags: ruby, translate, irb, rails-i18n

I don't understand why my method `translate` undefines `start_with?` method and is messing something in irb, so I can exit irb only by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, not `exit` or `quit`:

```
>> "hello".respond_to?(:start_with?)
=> true
>> def translate(string)                                                                                                                   
>>   if string.start_with?("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
>>     string += "ay"                                                                                                                      
>> end
>> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for #<RubyVM::InstructionSequence:0x00000001d4c960>
        from (irb):3:in `translate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> "hello".respond_to?(:start_with?)                                                                                                       
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:irb_binding@(irb)>:RubyVM::InstructionSequence
        from (irb):3:in `translate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> exit
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:irb_binding@(irb)>:RubyVM::InstructionSequence
        from (irb):3:in `translate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> quit
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:irb_binding@(irb)>:RubyVM::InstructionSequence
        from (irb):3:in `translate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>>
```

I tried two different workspaces and effect is the same.
My Ruby and Rails versions are:

```
~/workspace $ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
~/workspace $ rails -v
Rails 4.2.2
```

from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577814/what-is-translate-keyword-do-in-ruby) I know that word `translate` is used by many I18N libraries, so it's my only suspect, hence the title of this question. However as a beginner, I don't see any relation.

Comment: Your method works fine for me in irb. See if any of your code/libs do any monkey patching/refinements on `String`.

Comment: You say that your `translate` method undefines `String#start_with?`, but there is no indication of that in the transcript you showed. How did you determine that that is indeed what is happening?

Comment: @w0lf I read about this monkey patching. Honestly, I don't know how to check this, but if it's because of some gems I have installed only `ruby`, `rails`, `rspec` and `pry` on a blank cloud9 workspace.
@JörgWMittag `undefined method `start_with?'` Isn't that what you mean?
I tried `puts String.methods` but output is always the same, no matter what I type. I can only ctrl+d and restart irb.
I Also noticed this on fresh irb:
> def translate(s)
> puts s
> end
#<RubyVM::InstructionSequence:0x00000000a9a2e0>
 => :translate
I checked RubyVM in Ruby-doc but for now this is some arcane magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in YARV that was [fixed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/d8c3672b012ec6eb55e097162c6c638e8d932471) in YARV 2.4.0.

The commit message mentions the following workaround if you don't have YARV 2.4.0:

> ```
> class << RubyVM::InstructionSequence
>   def translate; end
>   undef translate
> end
> ```

Note that other implementations are not affected, only YARV.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theory

- There is probably a global function `translate` in your setup
- This function is called with an instruction sequence as argument when `irb` prints the output
- Hence when you redefine `translate` printing the output breaks

The `NoMethodError: undefined method` does not mean that the method has been undefined globally but that it is being sent to an object that does not understand it

You can test my theory by executing

```
method(:translate)
```

If you get a result back then `translate` is already defined and your must not redefine it!

Now if you want to know which gem defined this function, install `pry` gem (which is a better irb) and use the `$` command to look at the file and source code of that method

```
# Use this command in pry to see location and source code
$ translate
```